# Display alert box when table element has no text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, subquery, sparql

I have a table which automatically increments, it functions from a `Sparql` query, what it does is it gets an input from a user and using `dbpedia` it returns the `value` which is inside a table. So what I am trying to do is when the user inputs a invalid input instead of displaying a table with a blank `<td>` I want it to show a alertbox with something like - `Invalid Entry`. My codr is below:

**HTML**

```
 <table id="results">

   <Full name: 
    <br>
    <input id="userInput" type="text" name="fullname" ${userJson.userId == ''?'': 'disabled'} value="@ViewBag.DisplayName">
    <br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</table>
```

**Script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
            var table = $("#results");
            var url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
            var userInput = $('#userInput').val();
            table.on("click", "td", myFunction);

            var length = $.trim($("#userInput").val()).length;
            if (length == 0) {
                alert("null");
            }
            else {
                $('#userInput').prop('disabled', true);
                var query = [
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>",
            "PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>",
            "PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>",
            "SELECT ?spouse",
            "WHERE {",
                "?dave dbo:spouse dbr:" + userInput + ".",
                "?dave rdfs:label ?spouse.",
              "}",
            "Limit 1"
                ].join(" ");
                alert("this query: [" + query + "]");
                var queryUrl = url + "?query=" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&format=json";
                console.log(queryUrl);
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: queryUrl,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        // get the table element
                        var table = $("#results");

                        // get the sparql variables from the 'head' of the data.
                        var headerVars = data.head.vars;

                        // using the vars, make some table headers and add them to the table;
                        var trHeaders = getTableHeaders(headerVars);
                        table.append(trHeaders);

                        // grab the actual results from the data.
                        var bindings = data.results.bindings;

                        // for each result, make a table row and add it to the table.
                        for (rowIdx in bindings) {
                            table.append(getTableRow(headerVars, bindings[rowIdx]));
                        }
                    }
                });
                function getTableRow(headerVars, rowData) {
                    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
                    for (var i in headerVars) {
                        tr.append(getTableCell(headerVars[i], rowData));
                    }

                    return tr;
                }

                function getTableCell(fieldName, rowData) {
                    var td = $("<td></td>");
                    var fieldData = rowData[fieldName];
                    alert("fieldName = [" + fieldName + "] rowData[fieldName][value] = [" + rowData[fieldName]["value"] + "]");

                    //You need to check id fieldData["value"] is empty and then trigger alert, as if this empty your td will be empty
                    if (fieldData["value"] && fieldData["value"].trim().length !== 0) {
                        td.html(fieldData["value"]);
                        return td;
                    } else {
                        alert("td is empty");
                    }
                    console.log(td);
                }

                function getTableHeaders(headerVars) {
                    var trHeaders = $("<tr></tr>");
                    for (var i in headerVars) {
                        trHeaders.append($("<th>" + headerVars[i] + "</th>"));
                    }
                    return trHeaders;
                }
            }
        });

</script>
```

**SPARQL QUERY**

```
  $('#userInput').prop('disabled', true);
                var query = [
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>",
            "PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>",
            "PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>",
            "SELECT ?spouse",
            "WHERE {",
                "?dave dbo:spouse dbr:" + userInput + ".",
                "?dave rdfs:label ?spouse.",
              "}",
            "Limit 1"
                ].join(" ");
```

**My attempt**

```
function getTableCell(fieldName, rowData) {
                    var td = $("<td></td>");
                    var fieldData = rowData[fieldName];
                    alert("fieldName = [" + fieldName + "] rowData[fieldName][value] = [" + rowData[fieldName]["value"] + "]");

                    // check id fieldData["value"] is empty and then trigger alert, as if this empty your td will be empty
                    if (fieldData["value"] && fieldData["value"].trim().length !== 0) {
                        td.html(fieldData["value"]);
                        return td;
                    } else {
                        alert("td is empty");
                    }
                    console.log(td);
                }
```

With that code it just displays blank table if invalid input is entered and no alert box is shown.

Simply how can I show alert box when table contains empty element. Sorry for the long list of code I got the code from a source so do not fully understand it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It would be useful to see the JSON you are working with. Can you post a sample?

Comment: The json is used to convert the SPARQL query so it can be displayed in browser, I have put the sparql query in the question.

Comment: You just have to check if the JSON object is empty. For instance the bindings will be empty, thus, just add a check and if so show an alert instead of the table

Comment: @JesseLin Sure but I might get a different JSON result for any number of reasons. Without providing the JSON sample you are asking us to solve a problem with only half the clues. You can get the JSON into an html element by adding an element to your page as `<pre id="dump"></pre>` then `$("#dump").html(JSON.stringify(data))` where you currently log the data to the console.

Comment: if (data.results.bindings.length) {
    //exists
} else {
    alert('goes here');
}